# Shuffling variables in an array to output strings randomly

Tags: php

I created a form containing 4 boxes, if all 4 boxes have been filled the outputs are expected to shuffle into 4 groups. I have tried to used the array_rand() function but it will only randomise the output as instructed.

So i need it to shuffle without me knowing the sequence, which i tried to do but its not working as the database did not output the data.

How do i make it sync with the database? How do i make it work?

```
$a = array("$name1", "$name2", "$name3", "$name4");
shuffle($a);

$teamA = $a[0];
$teamB = $a[1];
$teamC = $a[2];
$teamD = $a[3];

$sql="INSERT INTO `teams`( `team_a`, `team_b`, `team_c`, `team_d`) VALUES ('$teamA','$teamB','$teamC','$teamD')";

$store= mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if($store){
    echo'Registration Sucessful';
}else{
    echo'Not sucessful';
}
```

Comment: Not clear what is wrong with current code.

Comment: Did you declare $conn somewhere?

Comment: sorry apparently the code worked successfully but i just had to clear my existing browsing data. Thanks for reaching out tho.